# Grouping Dynamic Map Service in WAB LayerlistWidget

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder

I am trying to organize my layers in the layerlistwidget based on categories, like none responsive text in between different category.

Is  there a way to do so without the need to group them in ArcMap?

I also experimented the add feature collection method as in the code below in my layerlistwidget startup function(see the code ) but the groups ("myGroupLayes" and " myGroupLayes2") are not visible in the layerlistwidget, instead all layers are listed in a flat hierarchy (see the graph below).

```
/ ***begin*** added code in startup() of LayerList/widget.js 
           // First group          
        var featureLayer1 = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://Feature layer URL");  
        featureLayer1.title = "featureLayer1";  
        var featureLayer2 = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://Feature layer URL");  
        featureLayer2.title = "featureLayer2";  
        var featureLayers = [featureLayer1, featureLayer2];  
        this.operLayerInfos.addFeatureCollection(featureLayers, "myGroupLayes");
           // Second group
           var featureLayer3 = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://Feature layer URL");  
        featureLayer3.title = "featureLayer3";  
        var featureLayer4 = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://Feature layer URL");  
        featureLayer4.title = "featureLayer4";  
        var featureLayersSecond = [featureLayer3, featureLayer4];  
        this.operLayerInfos.addFeatureCollection(featureLayersSecond, "myGroupLayes2");               
        // ***end*** added code in startup() of LayerList/widget.js
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Also does  the add FeatureCollection support dynamic layers too?

Or do we have another means to Group dynamic services as in the case of Feature layers?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to group layers as of yet in WAB 3.xxx ArcGIS API for JavaScript. It is possible in 4.xxx but WAB for developer edition is still using the 3.xxx API.